# How to generate the last 1 hour in seconds in unixtime?

Tags: linux, time

I'm wondering if there is a way of generating the unixtime seconds for the past hour. So 3600 timestamps. Is there a quick date command?

Comment: `date +%s` should give you the current time in seconds since the epoch. You can then do arithmetic on that and e.g. loop over the last 3600 values.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a job for `seq`:

```
seq "$(( $(date +%s) - 3599 ))" "$(date +%s)"
```

or to avoid a race condition due to "date" being executed twice:

```
NOW=$(date +%s); seq "$(( NOW - 3599 ))" "$NOW"
```

(3599 is so you get "3600 timestamps" as asked)

Comment: With newer versions of `bash`, you can do `seq "$((EPOCHSECONDS - 3599))" "$EPOCHSECONDS"` (that `$EPOCHSECONDS` was copied from `zsh` (in the `zsh/datetime` module there).

Comment: I think that gave me 3600 miliseconds. I changed it to 360000 and added sed -n '0~100p' and it seems to have done the trick! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    srand(); now = srand()
    for (i = now - 3599; i <= now; i++) print i
  }'
```

Anecdotally, that's based on the fact that traditionally, when `srand()` was called without a value, the current time was used instead. That was specified by POSIX though not explicitly that the epoch seconds were to be used. [I asked POSIX to clarify](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=983) and maybe allow implementations to use better sources of entropy to seed the pseudo-random generator, but [they chose to require that the unix epoch time be used](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=983#c3371), so the code above should be guaranteed to work for some time to come (as an exception, it doesn't currently work with OpenBSD `awk`).